# Call to a number, which contain #. (IPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to make call to a number, that start with #.
For example phone number in Russia looks like +79123817711 and I need to call #79123817711.
I'm trying this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://#79123817711"];
[[UIApplication sharedLibrary] openURL:url];
```

But it's replaced # with %23, and sure, not make a call.

Is there any way to make such calls.

I know, that is not a call, it's USSD request. But function of this ussd looks like a call.

Comment: Why do you need to call with # - I am working on a telephony related app myself so out of curiosity, I would like to understand why you ever need to use # in the phone number...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS SDK (Apple URL scheme reference) tells:
To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone application supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.

So, no luck.

Comment: I read it before, but may be there are another way to get access to gsm module...

Comment: If there is one (actually, it should be), it should be from 'private sdk' and will not be allowed on AppStore.

Comment: Any changes in the API?

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this by encoding the ussd and pass it in the url and it works just fine

Here is an example:

```swift
extension String {
      /// Calling ussd number
      func callUSSD() {
          guard let urlString = self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) else { return }
          guard let url = URL(string: "tel://\(urlString)") else { return }
         UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
@IBAction func callTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    "*1124#".callUSSD()        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace * by %2a and # by %23

Answer (score 0):

I tried iOS 10. But it was not working. But from iOS 12 now its working.
do not know how.

```
NSString *mobileNocleanedString = @"*454*200#";

NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",mobileNocleanedString]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
}
```