# Calling a number containing '#' with URLWithString

Tags: ios

I want to programmatically dial a number like `#123#`.

but `[NSURL urlWithString:@"tel://#123#"]` returns `nil`.

I cannot use string encoding because it will make the string change to `@"tel://%23123%23"` which couldn't be opened by `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554605/call-to-a-number-which-contain-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0):

If a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.