# Call short code phone number (e.g. *777) in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I know how to call phone number (e.g. 12345678) from iPhone App using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12345678"]];
```

But for phone numbers with `*` or `#`, the above line is not responding (no error message as well):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:*777"]];
```

Comment: Are you talking about something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554605/call-to-a-number-which-contain-iphone-sdk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is : iOS SDK does not allow phone numbers with * or # to be dialed in app.

Reference: [Call to a number, which contain #. (IPhone SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554605/call-to-a-number-which-contain-iphone-sdk)